# Borrar filas en distintas tablas mysql que tienen en común la misma clave foránea

Tags: php, mysql

Es la primera vez que publico por aquí. Solamente quiero dar las gracias por todos los problemas que he podido solucionar echando un vistazo en esta comunidad.

Ahora me encuentro con un problema, bueno, aún no porque estoy en fase de desarrollo y es un proyecto propio, aunque quiero ponerlo en funcionamiento cuanto antes mejor. Necesito vuestra ayuda o que me aconsejéis si lo estoy haciendo bien o podría hacerlo mejor.

He desarrollado un presupuestador en **Javascript** que va por pasos.

El cliente puede elegir que servicios necesita y según los servicios va mostrando unos formularios u otros. Todo ha ido genial y funciona a la perfección. Con **PHP** envío los datos introducidos en los campos y se registran en la base de datos.

La base de datos consta de **12 tablas**, cada una para un servicio. He creado una `foreing key` `id_presupuesto` que es común en todas ellas, ya que aunque el usuario no elija algunos servicios, quiero que se le asigne también el mismo `id_presupuesto` aunque los demás campos de la tabla queden en blanco.

Con ese `id_presupuesto` que es un `INT AUTO_INCREMENT` pinto con **PHP** cada presupuesto en una administración que he creado. Si hay servicios que no ha marcado no se pintan, solo se pintan los que ha marcado el usuario.

Todo funciona genial pero tengo una **duda/problema**. No me deja borrar ninguna fila por la dichosa `foreing key` y me gustaría crear en la administración un botón para poder borrar los presupuestos que quiera, la típica papelera jajjaj

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer una consulta en **MySQL** para borrar todas las filas de todas las tablas que tiene la misma `id_presupuesto`?

¿Hago bien en asociar la `foreing key` en todas las tablas?

Me gustaría ver opiniones de profesionales, ya que es mi primer proyecto con **PHP** y **MySQL**.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que tu buscas es borrar en cascada. Para eso usa en cada foreing key, Esto permitirá que cuando borres un registro se borren los demás en las otras tablas.

```
FOREIGN KEY (dni) REFERENCES clientes (dni) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Si haces bien en poner un foreing key o no, eso depende de la logica de diseño de bases de datos o de los requisitos que se necesite para que funcione correctamente la bd. 
Como consejo lee normalizacion de una bd eso te aclara muchos conceptos que necesitas para realizar un buen esquema de tu db. Saludos

Comment: Hola Juan y gracias por contestar. He probado la consulta que me envías y no me funciona, me dice "TIPO DE DECLARACIÓN DESCONOCIDA".

Answer (score 1):

¡Ya he conseguido hacer lo que quería!

Tenía mal estructurada la base de datos. Tomando como ejemplo esta publicación, he podido crear mi base de datos con las tablas relacionadas y funciona perfectamente.

[Borrar datos en cascada de varias tablas MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2917374/12475921)